# Как отключить масштабирование карты Конструктора колесом мыши

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-embed

Сделала карту в Конструкторе, чтобы она растягивалась на всю ширину страницы:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A053bd947d462cc1a45aeba4070defff75501905071c0eaf68436ac9976ec698c&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=351&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=true"></script>
```

Но теперь при прокручивании страницы колесом мыши курсор попадает на карту и меняет её масштаб. 
Можно ли отключить это поведение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Конструктора карт [есть API](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/constructor/concepts/About-docpage/) для настройки параметров виджета. Отключить масштабирование можно параметром `scroll=false`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?um=constructor%3A053bd947d462cc1a45aeba4070defff75501905071c0eaf68436ac9976ec698c&amp;width=100%25&amp;height=351&amp;lang=ru_RU&amp;scroll=false"></script>
```